# Unable to connect Metamask with Polygon

Tags: polygon, metamask, wallet-connect

When I try to connect Metamsk with Polygon below error message shows. how to fix this? it's just loading.  Oops! Something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Refer polygon docs for testnet/mainnet configuration here: https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/develop/metamask/config-polygon-on-metamask

1. **Use Polygon Scan**

To add the network manually, first, you need to go to the PolygonScan website. Once there, scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on Add Polygon Network.

2. **Add the Polygon Network Manually**

To add the Polygon Mainnet, click on the network selection drop-down menu in your MetaMask extension and select Network.

Network Name: Polygon Mainnet

New RPC URL: https://polygon-rpc.com

ChainID: 137

Symbol: MATIC

Block Explorer URL: https://polygonscan.com/